# How can I create a Pause function inside a class and then use it inside turtle game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, turtle-graphics

I was working on a snake game using turtle graphics in python. The game worked well.
Then, I wanted to improve on it and add a pause function to it. When I just wrote the lines of code for the pause function inside the game code, it worked, but my aim is to create the pause function in a class and be able to use its instance for my subsequent projects instead of just writing the whole functionality again every time.

Since the snake game code is long, I decided to try the pause function on a simple turtle animation to get the hang of it before implementing in my snake game but writing it in a class just isn't working.
Here's when I wrote it in the code, which worked:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tim = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
is_paused = False

def toggle_pause():
    global is_paused
    if is_paused:
        is_paused = False
    else:
        is_paused = True

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(toggle_pause, "p")

while True:
    if not is_paused:
        tim.forward(12)
        tim.left(10)
    else:
        screen.update()
```

Here's when I wrote my pause function in a class, which didn't work.

```
class Pause:
    def __init__(self, is_paused):
        self.is_paused = is_paused

    def toggle_pause(self):
        if self.is_paused:
            is_paused = False
            return is_paused
        else:
            is_paused = True
            return is_paused
```

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from pause import Pause

ps = Pause(False)
tim = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(ps.toggle_pause, "p")

pause = ps.toggle_pause()
while True:
    if not pause:
        tim.forward(12)
        tim.left(10)
    else:
        screen.update()
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean: `if not ps.is_paused:`?

Comment: Also it looks like you should get an error traceback. If so, can you update your question with its text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things to get the pausing to work in your game using the class:

1. Change the definition of the `Pause` class so it updates its `is_paused` attribute when its `toggle_pause()` method is called by adding a `self.` prefix to the `is_paused` variable name:

   ```
   class Pause:
       def __init__(self, is_paused):
           self.is_paused = is_paused

       def toggle_pause(self):
           self.is_paused = not self.is_paused
           return self.is_paused
   ```
2. Change the way the pause state is checked in the `while` loop in the main program:

   ```
   ...

   while True:
       if not ps.is_paused:
           tim.forward(12)
           tim.left(10)
       else:
           screen.update()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `pause` is only updated once, outside the `while` loop. You should use the class variable `self.is_paused` to test the state of the game.